# Is excessive greasing of coil pack terminals standard practise?

Tags: sparkplugs, ignition-coil, grease

I was swapping out some coil packs and found the ones in my car were packed with a ton of greese. Im quite impressed the vehicle was running at all with that much greese between the terminal and the plug.

Is this standard practise?

From the research I did, I understood that only a very little bit of grease is needed on the inner surface of the coil rubber/plastic (only) and optionally around the ceramic of the plug, but not the metal parts.

Please advise.

*Vehicle:
Ford Focus 2010 2.5L*

Answer (score 0):

The grease present should be *dielectric grease*. If so, there's no real issue. You don't need an excessive amount, but too much isn't going to cause issues. The grease is used to keep the electricity from going places it shouldn't as well as allow for the rubber of the plug ends not to stick to the coil pack or spark plug (easier removal without destroying the plug wire).

When it comes down to it, it depends on the person using it. There's no "industry standard" to make it *just right*.